# Recover Gmail password from iPhone or phone number?

Tags: google-account, password-recovery

My laptop has just died and I don't know my Gmail password. I do however have Gmail set up on my iPhone. Can I recover the password from this somehow? I was thinking either finding what the password is or being sent the password to the email account.

I know I've entered my phone number for some Google product. Can I be texted the password or recovery instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google account dashboard does not show you your password. The only option is to reset your password by entering both your current password and a new one.

One way to answer your question, since you have your phone is to try to log in on your phone's browser. At the login page select *Can't access your account?*

Follow the instructions to regain access to the password, although this will require you to reset your password. Your recovery options are dependent on whether you have selected recovery options for your account.

If you select "Recovery by phone," Google will either text or call you with a recovery code that you will enter on the following page in order to reset your password. You can always reset your password to be the same as what you *thought* your password was in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the question asked but I've managed to recover it by the Google Apps account.